# Mac, Python3.8, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyquery'

Tags: pip

I somehow installed pip successfully, but couldn't execute from pyquery

I really need help on this...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euJqy.png)

Comment: Can you try to install pip by: https://gist.github.com/haircut/14705555d58432a5f01f9188006a04ed

Comment: I tried, but can't